# proposicional logic in string matches combination

Tags: r, boolean, logic

I have a problem in R, when I want to do a combination of string matches, like:

```
X <- colnames(df[substr(colnames(df),start=1,stop=3) == "PEC" | substr(colnames(df),start=1,stop=5) == "PRE1_" & substr(colnames(df),start=1,stop=5) != "PEC3"])
```

X is going to be the df of independent variables for a future linear regression. X is composed by `PECZZZ`, `PRE1_ZZZ` where the `Z` character is any number between 0 and 9. `PEC3` is de dependent variable. So as the first string match will have `PEC3` as calling `PEC` implies `PEC3`, I'm using the third string match to delete it. However, the results for `PEC3` in the string matches above are:

```
TRUE | FALSE & FALSE = TRUE
```

Why? If `TRUE | FALSE = TRUE`, and `TRUE & FALSE = FALSE`. Or it doesn't follow the left-to-right common order rule?

Comment: better to wrap each chunk inside parens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R `&` precedes `|`. See for full list of operators and their order here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Syntax.html